# each column of table is having different width despite defining it and apply fixed table layout

Tags: css, angular

I am having a nested table which I am showing in the html. I am trying to have each column 50% Width but it is not working.

In the past when I need to do it, I apply `table-layout: fixed` and most of the time it works but this time it is not working.

What is wrong?
[editor link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tui9jh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<table class="employment" *ngFor="let item of empTabData| slice:1">
                <div class="container" fxLayout="row " fxLayout.xs="column">
                    <div class="item-1 " fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="100%">
                        <tr *ngFor="let i of item.employerInfo | slice:0:(item.employerInfo.length/2)+1">
                            <td class="emp">
                                {{i.key}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="emp">
                                {{i.value}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-1" fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="100% ">
                        <tr *ngFor="let i of item.employerInfo | slice:(item.employerInfo.length/2)+1:item.employerInfo.length">
                            <td class="emp">
                                {{i.key}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="emp">
                                {{i.value}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </table>

p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.employment {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.employment tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #fafafa;
}

.emp {
   width: 50%;
   white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


export class AppComponent  {
empTabData =  [{"employerInfo":[{"key":"UAN","value":"100460235222"}]},{"employerInfo":[{"key":"Matched Name","value":"UAT Test Aadhaar Name"},{"key":"User Id","value":"442ad831-983f-44ca-ac7f-e1851c911fb3"},{"key":"ID","value":"PYBOM00250170000001586"},{"key":"Employer","value":"EMIDS TECHNOLOGIES PVT LTD"},{"key":"Settled","value":"true"}]},{"employerInfo":[{"key":"Matched Name","value":"UAT Test Aadhaar Name"},{"key":"User Id","value":"442ad831-983f-44ca-ac7f-e1851c911fb3"},{"key":"ID","value":"PYKRP17189390000010001"},{"key":"Employer"},{"key":"Settled","value":"false"}]}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your tbody does not have a display set, and it is not going 100% width.
So try this:

```
tbody {
width: 100%;
display: table;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me when I change to `table-layout: fixed;`

```
tbody{
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.employment {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 1%;
}
.employment tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #fafafa;
}

.emp {
   width: 50%;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[image: Result]

Hope my answer helps you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put `<div>` as direct child of `<table>`. https://html.com/tables/ You 
have to draw your table starting from something like this.

```
<table class="employment" *ngFor="let item of empTabData| slice:1">   
    <tr *ngFor="let i of item.employerInfo | slice:0:(item.employerInfo.length/2)+1">
        <td class="emp">
            {{i.key}}
        </td>
        <td class="emp">
            {{i.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr *ngFor="let i of item.employerInfo | slice:(item.employerInfo.length/2)+1:item.employerInfo.length">
        <td class="emp">
            {{i.key}}
        </td>
        <td class="emp">
            {{i.value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For example, only by removing divs the size of td.emp (when they have enough space to do so) is 50%.